# Составление чисел из цифр меньших заданного числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан отсортированный массив `A` длины `n` (`n <= 10`) с цифрами, число `B` (`B <= 9`), и число `C` (`C <= INT_MAX`). Необходимо выяснить, сколько чисел длины `B` можно составить из цифр массива `A` таких, что эти числа меньше `C`.

Например:

```
A = {0, 1, 4, 7, 8}
B = 2
C = 42

Ответ: 7 (10, 11, 14, 17, 18, 40, 41}
```

Можно перебирать за `O(n^B)`, но нужно решение с дп, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Судя по вашему примеру - без повторов? 0 ведущим быть не может?

Comment: @Harry в числах цифры могут повторяться, в массиве - нет. Т.е. если в массиве указана цифра `1`, то мы можем использовать в числах её много раз

Comment: @Harry 0 ведущим не может

Comment: В условии сказано "Необходимо выяснить, сколько...". В ответе примера вдруг приведено не только количество, но ни с того ни с сего вдруг и сами числа перечислены. Так что же надо сделать-то? Определить сколько или вывести все числа?

Comment: Не вижу необходимости для ДП. Для чисел короче C (по количеству разрядов) ответ ясен сразу - там ничего отсеивать не надо и другого алгоритма существовать не может. Для чисел, равных C по количеству разрядов делаем перебор с отсеиванием. Понятно, что и этот перебор не должен быть "тупым" - нет смысла перебирать числа, чей префикс уже заведомо говорит, что они больше C (собственно в этом и заключается отсев). Вот и все.

Answer (score 3):

- Если `B` меньше, чем длина `C`, то ответ задачи вычисляется напрямую: либо `n^B`, либо `(n-1) * n^(B-1)` в зависимости от значения `A[0]` (не ноль или ноль).

  ```
  unsigned shorter_length_numbers(const unsigned A[], unsigned n_A, unsigned B)
  {
    unsigned n_numbers = A[0] > 0 ? n_A : n_A - 1;
    n_numbers *= power(n_A, B - 1);
    return n_numbers;
  }
  ```
- Если `B` равно длине `C`, то задача решается перебором чисел длины `B` из цифр `A`. Составляем числа в направлении от старших разрядов к младшим, сразу же отсекая перебор, когда промежуточное число больше или равно `C`.

  ```
  unsigned same_length_numbers(unsigned number, const unsigned A[], unsigned n_A, unsigned n, unsigned C)
  {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;

    unsigned weight = power(10, n - 1);

    unsigned n_numbers = 0;

    for (unsigned i_A = number > 0 || A[0] > 0 ? 0 : 1; i_A < n_A; ++i_A)
    {
      unsigned next_number = number + weight * A[i_A];
      if (next_number >= C)
        break;

      n_numbers += same_length_numbers(next_number, A, n_A, n - 1, C);
    }

    return n_numbers;     
  }

  unsigned same_length_numbers(const unsigned A[], unsigned n_A, unsigned C)
  {
    return same_length_numbers(0, A, n_A, log10_up(C), C);
  }
  ```

  Семантика функций `log10_up` и `power`, надеюсь, понятна и так.
- Если `B` больше, чем длина `C`, то ответ - 0.

Тот факт, что массив `A` отсортирован дает нам возможность проверять наличие нуля путем проверки `A[0]`, а также позволяет нам отсекать перебор всех остальных элементов массива в ситуации, когда значение `C` превышено.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436993e02829c71c